# Print last n number of lines of a file using c

Tags: c

Below is my function to display with `fp` the file pointer and `num` be the number of lines to print.   Right now, it again displays the complete file, not required lines, which I do not want.

```
void dispfile(FILE *fp, int num)
{

    long int pos;char s[100];
    int count;
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    pos=ftell(fp);

    while(pos)
    {
        fseek(fp, --pos, SEEK_SET);
        if(fgetc(fp)=='\n')
        {   
            if(count++ == num) 
            break;
        }
    }

    while(fgets(s, sizeof(s), fp))
    {
        printf("%s",s);
        //fputs(s, stdout);
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried your code and it worked for me.

Comment: how did it work.... to me it is showing the complt file again except the frst character.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reading last n lines from file in c/c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877025/reading-last-n-lines-from-file-in-c-c)

Comment: Initialize `count`.

Comment: Don't know why it's not working for you, unless the stream isn't seekable. You should check the return value of `fseek` to see if it's working.

Comment: @user58697 Post that as an answer.

Comment: @user58697 Thanks.... initialization worked.

Comment: There is a reason for compiler warnings: they point you at problems in your code. If your compiler did not warn already, enable all recommended warnings and pay heed to them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `count` is not initialized. It contains rather unpredictable garbage, and the condition `count++ == num` is satisfied in an unpredictable moment (strictly speaking, you have the UB).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by reading the file twice, the first time to count its lines, the second to skip some lines and then print up to `num` lines. If the file does not have `num` lines, all are printed. Assuming `s[]` will hold the longest line in the file.

```
void dispfile(FILE *fp, int num)
{
    int lines = 0;
    char s[100];

    rewind(fp);
    while(fgets(s, sizeof s, fp) != NULL) {
        lines++;                                // count the lines
    }

    rewind(fp);
    lines -= num;                               // lines to skip
    while(lines-- > 0) {
        if(fgets(s, sizeof s, fp) == NULL) {
            return;                             // unexpected EOF
        }
    }

    while(fgets(s, sizeof s, fp) != NULL) {     // print the rest
        printf("%s", s);                        // newline is already included
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to read the file twice actually.

Comment: @Olaf by caching in an array?

Comment: Ringbuffer of `char *` actually. But I'd not give code to OP, I don't see much effort in the code. Nor a specific problem. There's currently too many homework stuff being asked.

Comment: @Olaf you can submit that as an answer.

Comment: @Olaf he has at least tried, tried to count the `\n` characters.

Comment: @Olaf teacher won't believe that is the work of OP. What did you say about homework? It would be educational but not something that can be handed in as own work ;)

Comment: Also SEEK_END could be used as it was shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877025/reading-last-n-lines-from-file-in-c-c)